# How do i get a 2 decimal answer in this code? because i get more than 2

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class bmi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        float height,heightSquared,BMI;

        int weight;

        System.out.println("Your height in meters:");

        height = scan.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Your weight in kilograms:");

        weight = scan.nextInt();

        heightSquared = (height*height);

        BMI = weight/heightSquared;

        if (BMI < 18.5) {
            System.out.println("Your BMI result:"+ BMI + "(UNDER-WEIGHT)");
        }
        else if (BMI > 18.4 && BMI < 24.6) {
            System.out.println("Your BMI result:"+ BMI + "(NORMAL-WEIGHT)");
        }
        else if (BMI > 24.9 && BMI < 30) {
            System.out.println("Your BMI result:"+ BMI + "(OVER-WEIGHT)");
        }
        else {

            System.out.println("Your BMI result:"+ BMI + "(OBESSE)");
        }

    }
}
```

This is my code for getting the body mass index (BMI) of a person it's okay when running but my only problem is how do i turn the answer in 2 decimals?
for example:

Your height in meters:
 1.70
 Your weight in kilograms:
 50
 Your BMI result:17.301032(UNDER-WEIGHT)

i want the output to be only 17.30 or in 2 decimals.
what should i change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this. You can use `%2f` to get two decimal places

```
Your BMI result:"+ String.format("%.2f", BMI)
```

Comment: thanks it really worked but how did String.format("%.2f", BMI) do it?

Comment: @AmbenUchiha The method is called `format specifier specifies`. You can read through the API to get better understanding.